# Set sockopt of QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qtcpsocket, setsockopt

I am creating a Linux C++/Qt5 app which opens a TCP socket for an outbound connection (to a remote server).  I create a QTcpSocket and then try to set sockopt options as follows:

```
m_tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
int fd = m_tcpSocket->socketDescriptor();
int enableKeepAlive = 1;  // Enable
if ( setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &enableKeepAlive, sizeof(enableKeepAlive)) != 0)
    reportsockoptError("SOL_SOCKET","SO_KEEPALIVE");
```

Unfortunately my setsockopt is failing with 'Bad file descriptor' error, because m_tcpSocket->socketDescriptor() is returning -1.  How do I get the socket descriptor for an outbound socket before it connects?  Or do I have to do this AFTER connect?  (which seems to contract what I understand from the Qt docs)

The above works fine for a listening socket (QTcpServer)....just not QTcpSocket.

Comment: Why don't you use qt function `setSocketOption` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the QAbstractSocket documentation

> The socket descriptor is not available when QAbstractSocket is in
>   UnconnectedState.

So, before calling `socketDescriptor`, you should change the TCP socket internal state. In the case of a client socket, you probably need to connect it to a server, thus passing it to `ConnectedState`.

Comment: Seems to work...I think the Qt documentation is unclear on this.